# A more efficient way to check that there isn't a related item that has a certain value

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following method in one of my model classes. It's designed to let my views know that an JournalEntry can be edited. It should return true if the entry is not more than 90 days old and does not have *any* related LineItems that have a value in the LineItems reconciled_date field. Ie all the related LineItems must have NULL in their reconciled_date field.

The method works but it iterates thru the LineItems which seems very inefficient. Is there a better way?

Models.py

```
class JournalEntry(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=False, blank=False)
    date = models.DateField(null=False, blank=False)
    def can_edit(self):
        """Checks if logged user can edit"""
        is_reconciled = 0
        for lineitem in self.lineitem_set.all():
            if lineitem.reconciliation_date != None:
                is_reconciled = 1
        if (datetime.date.today() < (self.date + datetime.timedelta(90))) and is_reconciled == 0:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Thank you

Comment: It isn't immediately clear what lineitem_set is; you should post that model as well. Also, are you actually experiencing performance woes or just theorising? Everything can be optimised, but it's best to worry about performance only when it becomes an actual problem.

Comment: Can you share the line item model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform a single query that determines if the `JournalEntry` has any related line items that have a non-null reconciliation_date. It could be handy to have this in a property if you would like to re-use it in other methods

```
@property
def is_reconciled(self):
    """Returns True if any related line items have a non-null reconciliation_date"""
    return self.lineitem_set.filter(reconciliation_date__isnull=False).exists()
```

Then you can use this in your method

```
def can_edit(self):
    """Checks if logged user can edit"""
    # First check if the entry is less than 90 days old as it does not require
    # a call to the DB
    if self.date > datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=90):
        # If the entry is less than 90 days old then we return the inverse of is_reconciled
        return not self.is_reconciled
     return False
```